# React native undefined is not an object (evaluating '_react.PropTypes.arrayOf')

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-thunk

I have just created a new project in react native and configured it with redux as the following.

I start receiving the following error using npm run start

```
 LOG  loginReducer:: @@redux/INIT3.5.q.3.g.q undefined
 LOG  loginReducer:: @@redux/PROBE_UNKNOWN_ACTION5.z.m.u.9.l undefined
 LOG  todoReducer:: @@redux/INIT3.5.q.3.g.q undefined
 LOG  todoReducer:: @@redux/PROBE_UNKNOWN_ACTIONw.f.i.q.d.i undefined
 LOG  packageDetailReducer:: @@redux/INIT3.5.q.3.g.q undefined
 LOG  packageDetailReducer:: @@redux/PROBE_UNKNOWN_ACTION4.c.i.p.9.n undefined
 LOG  packageReducer:: @@redux/INIT3.5.q.3.g.q undefined
 LOG  packageReducer:: @@redux/PROBE_UNKNOWN_ACTIONx.x.j.i.c.p undefined
 LOG  GUIDEReducer:: @@redux/INIT3.5.q.3.g.q undefined
 LOG  GUIDEReducer:: @@redux/PROBE_UNKNOWN_ACTIONp.s.k.x.6.u undefined
 ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_react.PropTypes.arrayOf')
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
```

The strange thing is I have never used "_react.PropTypes.arrayOf" in my entire app. But yes I have used prop-types in two files, I have removed prop types totally but still not working.

**Index.js**

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';

import Myapp from './Myapp';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => Myapp);
```

Myapp.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import configureStore from './app/store/configureStore';

const store = configureStore({});

type Props = {};
export default class Myapp extends React.Component<Props> {
constructor(props){
    super(props);

}
render(){
return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <RootStack />
      </Provider>
    );

}
}
}
```

ConfigureStore.js

```
// @flow

// Redux Store Configuration
// import { createStore,applyMiddleware } from 'react-redux';
import {createStore,applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from '../reducer';
import loggingMiddleware from './middleware/logging';

const configureStore = (initialState) => {
  const middleware = applyMiddleware(thunk, loggingMiddleware);

  return createStore(rootReducer, middleware);
};

export default configureStore;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how are you exporting Myapp.js

Comment: Yes, I did export using a single line code.
"export default class Myapp extends React.Component<Props>"

Comment: did you remove proptype package ? install it again and check. i think some modules in your code need propType

Comment: Yes, I tried it, remove prop-types everywhere including the library but still no luck.